# I lost my SVN repository

Tags: svn

My **SVN repository** was installed on a server and this server got **down**,
I have three working copies and all of them made some changes and not commit them to the base
What to do in this case, please help me

Comment: get a new server and re setup the svn server.

Comment: Does this mean you have lost the repository?

Comment: @Groo: I seriously hope they made backups of the repository. If not, it's a great lesson for life ;-)

Comment: Thanks for you all, It's really a great lesson for my life.
The responsibility for this problem that I use my laptop as a repository location and I do not use an on-line server to host my repository.
I'll learn from that mistake and hope not to repeat that :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does this mean you have lost the repository?

In that case (if you have no backups at all) I guess the simplest thing to do would be:

1. Create a new repository somewhere.
2. Choose one of your working copies (start with the oldest one, i.e. the one with less changes).
3. Make a check-out of your new repository into an empty folder on that machine.
4. **Export** your working copy (do not copy it) to the empty folder you got in step 3. Since you are probably going to delete you old working copies later, it would be wise to **Export unversioned files** also (if you are using Tortoise SVN, there is a checkbox at the top of the Export dialog).
5. Commit you changes.

Repeat steps 2. to 5. for all working copies you have. During step 5., you will need to merge things manually. Take care to add any unversioned files, if needed.

You will have lost all the previous revision history, but no working data should be lost this way, provided that you have all the working copies.

Comment: A nice, clean fix if you don't have the repo backed up somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Make patches in each working copy, using `svn diff > a.patch`, then apply on one working copy patches from other two: `patch -p0 < a.patch`.

Next time, use some DVCS, something like Git or Mercurial :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a backup of the repository? If yes, load it with `svnadmin` somewhere and then commit the changes to this new place. Use `svn switch` to point your working copies to the new server.

If no, then you have lost the history of your project and there is no way to get it back.

All you can do is to create a new repository somewhere and commit the three individual copies one after the other to it. You may have to delete all `.svn` directories in your working copies to do that.

Use a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Version_Control_System) like [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/) to avoid situations like that (and lots of other problems).

Comment: I'm not convinced that advocating DVCS instead of a backup strategy is particularly sound advice.